# How to properly generate vimeo token for glitch aframe starter app

Tags: vimeo, demo

Here we have vimeo aframe demo app
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/33131776-fd15-4fb4-bf54-f46db97e5409

In .ENV file need to provide valid api key
e.q:

```
VIMEO_TOKEN=[TOKEN REDACTED] /*somewhy not valid api token*/
ENV=dev
```

Could you please provide working VIMEO_TOKEN.
why i need it? need to see demo vimeo a-frame component With video, not with empty blackscreen.

Comment: Your post is generally hard to understand, could you go over it again please

Comment: Ok, rewrited as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

You need a valid access token to interact with the Vimeo API. Note that direct video file links are only returned for Vimeo Pro members and higher: https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224823567-Third-party-player-links

Check out Vimeo's authentication docs here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication

Comment: okay, so key prhase here Note that direct video file links are only returned for Vimeo Pro members and higher .

Comment: Hello,  we have made pro trial , to be sure tha api key on glitch works, but can not get api key working. Please also see this github issue  https://github.com/vimeo/aframe-vimeo-component/issues/19

Comment: The goal, is: to make aframe video starter app on glitch (or on localhost aframe vimeo start app) to make it Work with generated api key , like here https://vimeo-authy.herokuapp.com/auth/vimeo/webgl

Comment: Are you generating a token with the `video_files` scope?

Comment: @KonstantinP See Table 1 here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#table-1